# C#, Android: Let the background "blur away" and exchange all buttons with new ones

Tags: c#, android

I am stuck on a little design feature. I have two screens in my app:
The Main Menu:

[image: Main Menu]

And the Categorys screen:
[image: Categorys]

Now, I wish to use the background set in the main menu also for the categorys screen. But I also want the background to blur out. (Just like when you click on the menu in your android phone and see the background blur out and dim a little). I need to remove all interface and replace it with the one from the categorys screen and have the previous background transition into blur. Does anyone here know how to achieve that? That be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Librarys :

https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

https://github.com/patrickfav/Dali

Thats Perfect and Helpful

Comment: Just what I was looking for! THANKS ! :)

Comment: Wait, this is all java. Do you maybe have something for c#?